# Asus vivopc compatible Ubuntu versions

Tags: system-installation, asus, usb-installation

Is there a version of Ubuntu that is compatible with Asus vivopc vc62b? I'm executing the installation from a USB.

Comment: I'd recommend Ubuntu MATE, since it tends to be a little more lightweight/faster than regular Ubuntu, but regular Ubuntu or Kubuntu would probably work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Any version of Ubuntu will work. Although I would recommend 16.04 x64 LTS.

Keep in mind you might experience difficulties with the Wi-Fi chip and/or the iGPU.